# Countour lines Matplotlib Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

If i have a list with tuples that reflects the position each time, and all I need is to have a graphic that shows this vectores as countour lines of the velocity (another list). How shoud I do it?

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
position = [(12,14), (12.22,13.22), (15, 17)]
velocity = [4.55,2.13,5]
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  How do you propose to generate a contour line from such limited data?  Typically contours are used to provide a two-dimensional representation of the value of a two-input function (e.g., elevation at various points).  You just have a few isolated numbers.

Comment: It's just the idea. Supose that I have the position as a list of vectors, and the velocity for each position. I need a graphic that joins me each vector of position with its velocity. I thought that the countour line would do it great. Don't you think? I'm not sure how should I have to do it

Comment: A contour line (also isoline, isopleth, or isarithm) of a function of two variables is a curve along which the function has a constant value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use griddata() to convert scatter points in to grid data, here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(0)

x = np.random.normal(size=200)
y = np.random.normal(size=200)
v = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)

xg, yg = np.mgrid[x.min():x.max():100j, y.min():y.max():100j]
vg = griddata((x, y), v, (xg, yg), method='cubic')
plt.contourf(xg, yg, vg)
plt.scatter(x, y, c=v)
plt.show()
```

The output is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to plot the velocity at each point then you should try `quiver`. It makes a direction field (arrows) plot. As velocity is vector quantity it has both an `x` and `y` component.

```
import pylab as plt

x=[12, 13, 14, 15, 16] # x-axis coordinates
y=[14, 15, 16, 17, 18] # y-axis coordinates

v_x=[6, 6, 6, 6, 6] # x-component of velocity
v_y=[1,4,3,2,1]     # y-component of velocity

plt.quiver(x,y,v_x,v_y)
plt.xlim(11,17)
plt.ylim(13,19)

plt.show()
```

Have a look [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/quiver_demo.html) if you want to learn more about `quiver`.

In contrast, `contour` is curves along which some variable has a constant value. Have a look [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html) if you want to learn more.